# WCF SQL adapter issue while inserting the records into a SQL Server 2012 tables

Tags: wcf, sql-server-2012, biztalk

Issue while inserting the records into the SQL Server 2012 table using the WCF SQL adapter. I am getting the following error message.

> Error details: Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.XmlReaderParsingException: The start element with name "NewDataSet" and namespace "http://www.ATM.Schemas.ATMAcquirerTransactionsDetails" was unexpected. Please ensure that your input XML conforms to the schema for the operation.
>
> URI:  mssql://WIN-UHMK25Q5BMH/BLUECLOUDSQL/ATM?
>
> Action: TableOp/Insert/dbo/ATMAcquirerTransactionsDetails

Please help me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Root Node Name and Namespace properties you configured on your WCF-SQL Adapter do not correspond to the Root Node Name and Namespace present on the message that you are sending to the Adapter.

You might want to check the message you are sending and change the adapter properties accordingly; or map the message to the correct Root Node Name and Namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem. This is perhaps because the schema contains more than one element (NewDataSet must be the second, judging by my case). This means you are trying to write simultaneously to two tables. I haven't figured out a solution yet.